# Passing SQLalchemy query results to start_urls in scrapy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

Using scrapy in a Python 2 environment, I want to use sqlalchemy to query a database for a list of URLs, and then send that URL list to scrapy, to be used as its list of start_urls.

The filename is betsy.py and I execute this whole affair by typing:

> scrapy runspider betsy.py

This is supposed to be a fairly simple program to double-check for 404s, etc. I don't need to do any further crawling once I reach these URLs.

Here's what I think is the relevant code:

```
class LandingPages(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'landingpages_programmatic'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    campaign_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    ad_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    ad_url = Column(String(512), nullable=True)
    ad_url_utm = Column(String(512), nullable=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime(),default=datetime.now)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "'{self.ad_url}'".format(self=self)

todaysdate = str(datetime.now().year) + '-' + str(datetime.now().month) + '-' + str(datetime.now().day)
unique_landingpages =  session.query(LandingPages).filter(LandingPages.created_on.startswith(todaysdate)).limit(2).all()

class BetsySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name='BetsySpider'
    start_urls = [unique_landingpages]

    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        title = response.css('h1::text').extract_first()
        print('URL is: {}'.format(url))
```

If I add this line just after the unique_landingpages variable is set:

`print unique_landingpages`

Then I see the seemingly usable results:

`['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.bing.com/']`

However, I have no success passing these results onto scrapy's start_urls argument.

If I try start_urls = unique_landingpages, I get this error:

> File "/Users/chris/Desktop/Banff Experiments/banff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 56, in _set_url
>       raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).**name**)
>
> TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got LandingPages:

If I try start_urls = [unique_landingpages], I get this error:

> File "/Users/chris/Desktop/Banff Experiments/banff/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py", line 56, in _set_url
>       raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).**name**)
>
> TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:

However, when I run this in Mac Terminal and then copy the output of **print unique_landingpages**, as shown above, and then directly paste that into betsy.py, so that it says:

```
start_urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.bing.com/']
```

it runs perfectly fine.

I've searched a dozen or so articles on here but don't see anyone else with this same situation. Can anyone kindly shed some light on where I've gone wrong?

(Incidentally, there's probably a much cleaner way to filter by today's date.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning two instances of `LandingPages` objects. You can either change the query so that only the `ad_url` values are returned, or extract the `ad_url` attribute of each `LangingPages` instance that is returned.

Option 1:

```
unique_landingpages =  session.query(LandingPages.ad_url).filter(LandingPages.created_on.startswith(todaysdate)).limit(2).all()
```

Option 2:

```
unique_landingpage_records =  session.query(LandingPages).filter(LandingPages.created_on.startswith(todaysdate)).limit(2).all()
unique_landingpages = [u.ad_url for u in unique_landingpage_records]
```

If you only need the `ad_url` field of each record, use option 2, as the query will be less expensive.

The `print` statement is misleading because you have defined a `__repr__` method for the `LandingPages` class. `print` looks for that method and uses it when trying to figure out how to print what you give it.

Comment: Ahh, so the "dep __repr__ self:" section only tells the program how to display the results *on screen*, but not actually in memory. And so if I remove the dep __repr__ self: snippet, I can see what "unique_landingpages" is really being stored as, which is: "[<betsy.LandingPages object at 0x10dad78d0>, <betsy.LandingPages object at 0x10dad71d0>, <betsy.LandingPages object at 0x10dad74d0>"........ and so on. 
Thanks again. That was an important concept for me to digest. Really appreciate the help.